# ¿Cómo podría llamar a un comando al dar clic en una reacción? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Tengo un evento on_raw_reaction_add y estoy intentando que al presionar una reacción hacer una llamada a alguno de los comandos como saludo(ctx) que envía un saludo con una mención, utilicé

```
result = await saludo()
await message.channel.send(result)
```

Este es mi evento que actualmente sólo quita la reacción que agrega el usuario

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if channel.guild is None:
        return
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    if emoji == "":
        reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
        if reaction and reaction.count > 1:
            await reaction.remove(payload.member)
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llamalo directamente, a mi me funcionó, creo que esto serviría:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if channel.guild is None:
        return
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    if emoji == "":
        reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
        if reaction and reaction.count > 1:
            await comandoallamar(ctx) #Llamando al comando
            await reaction.remove(payload.member)
            pass
```

Y si eso no funciona mete el comando al que estás llamando dentro de una clase y luego llamalo, por ejemplo:

```
class EstaEsLaFucion():
    @bot.command()
    async def comandoallamar(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Contenido") #Test

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    if channel.guild is None:
        return
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    if emoji == "":
        reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
        if reaction and reaction.count > 1:
            await EstaEsLaFucion.comandoallamar(ctx) #Llamando al comando
            await reaction.remove(payload.member)
            pass
```